# How do I get Lando mysql portforward to work with lamp recipe

Tags: mysql, docker-compose

[This isn't directly about docker, but I couldn't add lando as a tag.]

Every time I stop and restart my Lando app, the external mysql port changes.  This is because the database in the lamp recipe is set to portforward rather than to a specific port. I want a consistent port so that I don't have to keep change host phpMyAdmin config.inc.php file every time I reboot my computer.

Here's my current .lando.yml:

```
name: test
recipe: lamp
config:
  webroot: www
  php: 7.2
  conf:
    php: config/php/php.ini
  db:
    portforward: 32792
```

The portforward setting doesn't work: I still get a new external mysql port on rebuild.  I've tried various alternatives to no avail.

Any ideas on how to correct the above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an answer on the Lando slack channel.  I needed to change

```
  db:
    portforward: 32792
```

to

```
services:
  database:
    portforward: 32792
```

where services aligns fully on the left and is not an entry under config.